# which storage scenario to choose with openstack? Ceph cluster, or SAN

Tags: openstack, cloud, storage, ceph

We are building an OpenStack cloud in my organization. My original plan was to work with a Ceph cluster as back-end for Cinder, Glance and Swift. But we have a Dell SC series SAN in the datacenter with up to 50TB of storage.

My question: is it possible to create a Ceph cluster using the SAN or should we just use Swift nodes with this SAN storage?

Answer (score 0):

Most OpenStack clusters out there have Ceph-backed storage along the lines of your original plan -- see the [Foundation's user survey](https://www.openstack.org/assets/survey/April-2016-User-Survey-Report.pdf).

Using the SAN to back Ceph makes little sense: Ceph is designed to use cheap off-the-shelf servers with replication across them for resiliency (no RAID), while a SAN is designed to be reliable, replicates data across drives in RAID, and comes with a price tag to match. Laying one on top of the other is a strange match, and you lose the economics of using cheap servers for next-gen Ceph storage alongside your next-gen compute from OpenStack.

If you want (or have to) use the SAN in your design, I would go with your second option: use the SAN to serve Swift, and use a stand-alone Ceph cluster to serve block to Cinder, Glance and Nova.

Comment: thank you 0xF2 for your reply, right now i'm going to use both SAN and Ceph as you suggested, but why would you use SAN with swift and not with glance?, because it make sense having fiber channel connection with SAN serving volumes for VMs

Comment: Oh, tech-wise you can use the SAN to serve more than Swift, but I thought you gave me two options to choose from above. Still, it makes sense to use software-defined storage with OpenStack (next gen storage with next-gen compute), so you aren't stuck with legacy storage economics for your cloud. In that view, using Ceph for all block services makes more sense than splitting them up, but you could still use the SAN for object until Swift starts to consume too much space.